# npx create-fusion-app not working. fusion.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, npx, fusionjs

On running **npx create-fusion-app my-app** I am getting following error.
npm version is 5.6.0, node version is 8.11.2.

```
Creating a new Fusion.js app in: /Users/vivek/vivek/fusion-framework-try/my-app

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 2):

We've tracked this down to an issue where the scaffolder currently depends on yarn being installed. We'll need to do some work to enable running without yarn, but for now a quick fix is to install yarn on your system. We'll track this issue here:  https://github.com/fusionjs/create-fusion-app/issues/27

Note: Ideally we could have a `fusion-js` tag created for this, as this is related to the framework here: http://fusionjs.com/

Comment: Yeah..Kevin, I got the information from that issue only. Thanks. There is no official tag for fusion js right now here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @KevinG I've created a tag for fusionjs and added in this post.